# socat streaming UDP is slower than TCP

Tags: dns, udp, socat, network-namespaces

I'm currently using `subprocess.run(["socat", f"udp-listen:{_to},fork,reuseaddr,bind=127.0.0.1", f"""exec:'sudo ip netns exec {netns} socat STDIO "UDP-connect:127.0.0.1:{_from}"',nofork"""])` to forward a UDP port from a network namespace to the host. However, forwarding UDP ports is much slower than forwarding TCP ports with the same method (the UDP service is question is a self-hosted AdguardHome DNS server, if it matters). Why is that?

Edit:
I'm not sure how important this is, but I've only found this on the UDP.

```
fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
recvfrom(3, 0xffffcb0f4460, 519, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
bind(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
getsockname(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
recvfrom(3, 0xffffcb0f4240, 519, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Comment: What exactly are you measuring? Also note that TCP is optimized for throughput and reliability while the focus of UDP is low latency, even at the cost of data loss.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I didn't measure anything exactly, but I've tested all combinations of "service on {host, namespace}" and "DNS on {host,namespace}", and whenever the DNS server is in the namespace, it takes far longer to get back a DNS response, and therefore, takes longer for the page to load.

Comment: What does `strace` and `tcpdump` show going on? Last I looked `socat` was pretty inefficient with UDP, so I wrote a UDP tunnel not using `socat`

Comment: @thrig Updated. What tool did you end up using (or was it completely your own code)?

Comment: Totally custom code.